# Using Metaclasses for self-registering plugins? (Approach help)

Tags: python-2.7, dynamic, plugins, metaclass

I'm trying to write a Python (2.7) library which loads certain classes at runtime. These classes contain a predefined set of methods.

My approach is to define a few Metaclasses which I work with in my library. I would for example define a "Navigation" Metaclass and work with it in the library. Then someone could write a class "Mainmenu" which contains some type of type definition that it is a "Navigation" plugin. And then the Library could use this class.

I am able to load modules and I'm able to write Metaclasses. My problem lies in combining these two things.

First there is the problem that I want the "plugin-classes" to be in a different (configurable) folder. So I can not do:

```
__metaclass__ = Navigation
```

because the Navigation class is part of my library and won't be there in the plugin-folder...
How could I solve the Problem of telling the type that the plugin is for? (Navigation, content.... e.g)

**EDIT2: I solved the following problem. I found out that I can just ask the module to give me a dict.
My first problem still exists though**

EDIT:

I managed registering and loading "normal" classes with a registry up until the following point:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import imp


class State:
    registry = {}

    def register_class(self,target_class):
        self.registry[target_class.__name__] = target_class
        print target_class.__name__+" registered!"

    def create(self,classname):
        tcls = self.registry[classname]
        print self.registry[classname]
        return tcls()

s = State()
mypath = """C:\metatest\plugins"""
files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
for f in files:
    spl = f.split(".")
    if spl[1] == "py":
        a = imp.load_source(spl[0], mypath + """\\""" + f)
        s.register_class(a)
```

The problem I have at the end now is, that "a" is the loaded module, so it is a module-object. In my case there is only one class in it.
How can I get a Class object from the loaded module, so I can register the class properly??

Comment: First thing to note there: if this is Python 2,  yur classes _have_ to inherit from `object` (having a proper metaclass set will do that for you). Otherwise it is an "old style" class, and a lot of mechanisms taken for granted simply won't work on your objects.
Second thing: you are not using Python 3 in new code because?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So - let's check your problem steping back on your current proposal.
You need a way to have plug-ins for a larger system - the larger system won't know about the plug-ins at coding time - but the *converse* is not true: your plugins should be able to load modules, import base classes and call functions on your larger system.

Unless you really have something so plugable that  plug-ins can work with more than one larger system. I doubt so, but if that is the case you need a framework that can register interfaces and retrieve classes and adapter-implementations between different classes. That framework is Zope Interface - you should read the documentation on it here: https://zopeinterface.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Much more down to earth will be a plug-in system that sacans some preset directories for Python files and import those. As I said above, there is no problem if these files do import base classes (or metaclasses, for the record) on your main system: these are already imported by Python in the running process anyway, their import in the plug-in will just make then show up as available on the plug-in code.

You can use the exact code above, just add a short metaclass to register derived classes from State - you can maketeh convention that each base class for a different plug-in category have the `registry` attribute:

```
class RegistryMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        for base in cls.__mro__:
            if 'registry' in base.__dict__:
                  if cls.__name__ in base.registry:
                       raise ValueError("Attempting to registrate plug-in with the name {} which is already taken".format(cls.__name__))
                  base.registry[cls.__name__] = cls
                  break
        super(RegistryMeta, cls).__init__(name, base, namespace)

class State(object):
    __metaclass__ = RegistryMeta
    registry = {}
    ...
```

(keep the code for scanning the directory and loading modules - just switch all directory separation bars to "/" - you still are not doing it right and is subject to surprises by using "\")

and on the plug-in code include:

```
from mysystem import State

class YourClassCode(State):
   ...
```

And finally, as I said in the comment : you should **really** check the possibility of using Python 3.6 for that. Among other niceties, you could use the `__init_subclass__` special method instead of needing a custom metaclass for keeping your registries.

Comment: Thanks! I still have to fully understand all that but it seems to be exactly what I want! I'd use Python 3.6 but I can't... Existing structures and bosses and stuff :D

Comment: Okay. Looked at this in detail now and there a a few things i dont relly get here:

Comment: 1. I see the State Object as an object for holding and maintaining the registry of loaded Plugins. why would I want the plugins to inherit from State?

2. i think I don't completly get what is going on here. is there a more elgant way to keep State itself out of the registry than "and cls.__name__ != "Plugin""

3. Where do (*args, **kwargs) come from?

4.I don't really get the sentence "you can make the convention that each base class for a different plug-in category have the registry attribute"

Comment: Ah I think I get it now. You mean I can have different versions of the State class for the different Plugin categories, right??

Comment: Yes.  - Different classes for different Plug-in categories. args and kwargs are there just due to copy and paste error froma  previous idea I had  - I've fixed them now.

Comment: As for the elegant way to keep State out of the registry - - that comparison would work. You can also check if "cls is base" - in which case the class is tryng to register itself if there is a registry, and `continue`.